# How to display text against radio button on console in Selenium Webdriver? What method should I use?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I want to display text of selected radio button on console, what method should I use?

I am using:

```java
System.out.println("Status:"+driver.findElement(By.name("Status").getAttribute("value")));
```

to display selected status value but name, id are same for all the given statuses, its displaying the first status available in form not selected one. I have also tried with cssSelector and xpath, issue is same.

Comment: iterate through all the values and check whether the radio button is selected or not using  isSelected() ...if isSelected() == true get the value.

Comment: @SadhaNanda  its displaying same id and name for all the given options on inspecting (id="Status" and name="Status" for all radio buttons), what should I do now?? How can i iterate in this case?

Comment: you need to share html with us  for same so we can see and help you